# Can I respect a user's "Open links in new tab" setting in an SPA?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, progressive-enhancement

Say we have a single-page application with a link:

```html
<a href="/products/12">Shampoo</a>
```

Regardless of UI framework, we can capture the click and handle the navigation without a reload, rearranging the UI and using the history API. By using `<a href..>` as the basis, regular links behaviours such as being able to copy the URL or open the link in a new tab are preserved.

However, the user browser preference "open all links in a new tab" is not respected because we capture the click before the browser gets to it. **Question:** is there a way to respect such settings without a page reload?

I thought there might be a way to capture and handle (same-origin) navigation *just* before it happens but there don't seem to be any APIs for that.

Comment: Does anybody actually use "open links in new tabs" as their preferred setting? Regardless, if the user really wants to open a link from such a page in a new tab, they can ctrl-click the link. Just make sure your link handling code knows to not manage the link if ctrl was used. As far your question: There's `beforeunload` and `unload` but you can't prevent those.